# Bukkit - Why does a certain piece of code only work on OPs?

Tags: java, bukkit

For some reason a piece of my code only works with OPs. And this piece of code is probably one of the only ones that is meant to NOT work with OPs.

My code is at:
http://pastebin.com/sQeeXRNN

Now, the bit that isn't working is the

```
@EventHandler
public void onInventoryClick(InventoryClickEvent event) {
if(!event.getWhoClicked().isOp()) {
//rest of it
```

Which as the `if(!event.getWhoClicked().isOp()) {` is clearly stating as only working for people who aren't Op. I have tried without the `if` statement and it still only works for OPs. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Jay

Comment: I would suggest adding some logging statements before the isOP check. Output the name of the user returned from getWhoClicked as well as the result of isOP. I expect that will give you a good idea of what is going on.

Comment: Maybe check if the server your testing/using this on has a plugin that ops everybody... Also double-check the tester isn't an op (I know, it sounds stupid, but that may be the problem), and maybe delete the `ops.json`/`ops.txt` file if you need to

Answer (score 0):

using

```
if(!e.getWhoClicked().isOp())
{
    // code
}
```

will not work because `InventoryClickEvent#getWhoClicked()` returns a HumanEntity. This is not a player.

To fix this issue you would first cast `getWhoClicked()` to a player like so:

```
Player player = (Player) e.getWhoClicked();
if(!player.isOp())
{
    // continue code
}
```

You must always make sure that something is returning a player before checking if it is op.

Answer (score -1):

Last time I checked, using these kind of checks are deprecated, use the permission system instead:

```
if (!event.getWhoClicked().hasPermission("yourplugin.bypassclick"))
```

and give that permission to ops inside your `plugin.yml` :

```
permissions:
  yourplugin.*:
    description: Gives all permission
    children:
      yourplugin.bypassclick: true
  yourplugin.bypassclick:
    description: Gives the permission to <do something>
    default: op
```

Comment: Thing is, even without the if statement it still only works for OPs. Idk why use a perm would be any better?

Comment: @user3798369 because it relies on proper permission mechanics, and if you ever want to change the access (give the bypass to certain groups or on certain events), you just have to add/revoke the permission, not change the plugin.

Comment: These checks are not depricated, Bukkit still lets you (and wants you) to use .isOp()

Comment: @Jojodmo sorry, but no, the permission system has been introduced specifically to address the issues inherent to the op system. Calling isOp() now is the equivalent of bringing upon you the fires of every single admin out there that would use your plugin with a permission system, but can't because of this limitation. So while bukkit does not explicitely prevent you from using this, that does not mean you *should* when you think of publishing said plugin afterwards.

Comment: Considering this would be a plugin that I'm coding for one server only, this is irrelevant. Also I fixed anyway, somehow a simple restart of the server fixed it.

Answer (score -2):

Weirdly, a simple restart of the server fixed the issue.